# OBS 27 has no Wayland option on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: wayland, 21.04, obs-studio, pipewire

So, as you can see I have pipewire installed but there is no option for it. And yes, I installed OBS from its PPA that means it is up to date (27.0.1)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I just need to say OBS to use Wayland with `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland obs`

Comment: An additional way is to run `obs -platform wayland` - at least for me.

Comment: @amenthes Well, there is the easiest option as well. Just install flatpak version, it's not broken as PPA version and works out of the box