# Screen recording softwares not working in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: video, 21.04, obs-studio, kazam

Screen recording softwares such as Kazam and Simple Screen Recorder are not working in my ubuntu 21.04 pc. The screen gets recorded but when I view the video only black screen appears with  mouse cursor moving here and there. I first thought that the problem is in video player. I am using VLC media player. So I tried few other video players too but with all of them I had the same issue. I used OBS studio for recording and to my surprise the screen got recorded and there was no black screen but that software too had a problem that the video was too noisy and the audio was also distorted. Anyhow, my problem is that why other screen recording softwares are not working and showing only black screen?

Comment: Switch to Xorg session.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks!! It worked for me.

Comment: Duplicate of [Ubuntu 21.04 any screen recorders not working. Showing black screen only!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347489/ubuntu-21-04-any-screen-recorders-not-working-showing-black-screen-only)

Answer (score 3):

These screen recorders do not support modern Wayland session.

So you have to use Xorg session. Switch to it from login screen.

Answer (score 1):

There are some screen recorders for the modern Wayland too (you need not switch to the older Xorg for that)

I got these from a simple Internet search:

https://itsfoss.com/kooha-screen-recorder/

https://itsfoss.com/screen-record-obs-wayland/
https://itsfoss.com/screen-record-obs-wayland/