# How to record audio with the built-in screen recorder (Ubuntu 22.04)?

Tags: 22.04, desktop-recording

I tried recording my screen on Ubuntu 22.04 and the resulting video does not have audio.

Is there any way to get it to record audio as well?

Comment: Did u get a solution for this? i am also stuck on this issue

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, as confirmed on [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493173) on Ubuntu Forums. But there is other screen recording software that does do this. Due to the implementation of the Wayland protocol in 22.04, two popular screen recorders I previously used (Kazam and SimpleScreenRecorder) don't work without tinkering, as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347489/ubuntu-22-04-any-screen-recorders-not-working-showing-black-screen-only). A number of possible interventions are suggested there and elsewhere, some of which could make Kazam or SSR work; but to me the simplest seems to be to use a different, Wayland-compatible recorder. The recommendations others made are newer versions of Kooha and OBS Studio. I plan to try both.